# Java - Global variable or something

Tags: java, variables, interface

I'm having problem understanding an assignment in Java. Basicly we are writing an interpreter and should be simple. I have not used Java for over 2 years so nearly all my knowledge is forgotten.

Basicly, the classes I need to create look like theese.

```
    public interface Handler {
            void interpret(); 
    }


    public class Program implements Handler{
    @Override
        public void interpret() {
        // write the interpret logic here
        }
    }


    public class Stmt implements Handler {
    @Override
        public void interpret() {
            // write the interpret logic here
        }
    }

    public class Move extends Stmt implements Handler {

        public void interpret() {
        // write the interpret logic here
        }
    }
    public class Right extends Move implements Handler {
        public Right( Exp i )
        {
        interpret();
        }
        public void interpret() {
        // write the interpret logic here
        }
    }
```

And the test program needs to be like this:

```
Program pro_inst = new Program();
pro_inst.addStmt(new Start(new Exp(new Numbers(23)), new Exp(new Numbers(
pro_inst.addStmt(new Forward(new Exp(new Numbers(15)) ) );
        ... ...
pro_inst.addStmt( new Stop());
... ..
```

I've fooled around for some hours but I struggle hard. For example, where do I assign variables and how can i edit them using the interpreter? I see that I'm creating new Objects all the time in my test program, should I return values or what? I need to have a variable x and y somewhere and they all need to be edited by the interpreter.

Thank you if you read so far!

Comment: `Program pro_inst = new Program();` With this line, you created a variable and assigned something to it

Comment: Did you stop programming altogether for the past 2 years or so?

Comment: Does the classes Move and Right needs to implement Handler when they are extending Stmt ?

Comment: Yes. This is direct copy of teachers notes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to understand the idea of scope.

Your program class is adding different actions (start, stop , move, etc... ) which are each encapsulated by a "Handler".

Each handler does something.  It is up to you to define the interpret code blocks.

Thus, to make your program work, you will have to add variables to the Program class, and modify those variables in your interpret() methods.

Comment: I know the idea of scope. My teacher wrote the mentioned program and wants us to use it the way it is. When I call `new Forward ( new Exp( new Numbers(15)))` I need to get the global x-variable and add 15 to it, if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how you mean this to go. but when you instantiate any object, you should store the data using in the object using the constructor -

```
public class Numbers extends Expr{
  double value = 0;
  public Numbers(double x){
   this.value = x;
  }
  public Object evaluate(){
   return value;
  }
}

public class Start extends Stmt{
  Vector<Expr> expressions = new Vector<Expr>();
  public Stmt(Expr x1, Expr x2){
   expressions.add(x1);
   expressions.add(x2);
  }
  public void interpret(){
   // do something with your list of 'expressions'
  }
}
```

The objects, which are instantiated when you execute the test program, should store those values that are passed in the constructor, like above.

for example, if you want to have an assignment, something like this should be constructed

```
class Assignment extends Stmt{
 String lhs;
 Expr rhs;
 public Assignment(String lhs, Expr rhs){
  this.rhs=rhs; this.lhs=lhs;
 }
 public void interpret(Map context){
    context.put(lhs, rhs.evaluate());
 }
}
class VariableExpr extends Expr{
  String name;
  public VariableExpr(String name){ 
   this.name=name;
  }
  public Object evaluate(Map context){
   return context.get(name);
  }
}
```

You will need to have a context for every statement at the time it is interpreted.
If you want a global context, just start with a blank `HashMap`, and pass the same map to each call of the `interpret` methods.

Sorry if this isn't what you are asking!

Comment: I see your point, but is really context only way to go? I need the follow the program structure in my opening post, or else I will fail. It's a simulation of a language written in BNF.